# What can I do against floating point notations Errors?

Tags: java, floating-point, multiplication, floating-accuracy

I need to multiply a `float` by `100` in order to convert from `€` to `cents`. The problem I am having is, that the value of big numbers isn't calculated correctly.

For example:

```
String aa = "1000009.00";
aa = aa.replaceAll(",", ".");
float bb = Float.parseFloat(aa);
bb=Math.round(bb*100);
System.out.println(bb);
```

What I am getting is: `1.00000896E8`

So I know this is because of the way `float` in Java works. 
I have searched for an answer but people always say "use `Math.round()`" which doesn't work for me.

What can i do to prevent this?

Comment: Use `double` instead of `float`.

Comment: Or even better use `BigDecimal` instead of `float`.

Comment: `float` has [6 to 9 significant decimal digits precision](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single-precision_floating-point_format#IEEE_754_single-precision_binary_floating-point_format:_binary32), and your number `1000009.00` is 9 digits long. You've exceeded the precision of `float`. Use `double` (15–17 digits) or `BigDecimal` (unlimited precision) instead.

Comment: Generally, don't use floating point for calculations where the exact decimals in base10 are important (e.g. money), its going to bite you at some point, especially if you're not 100% certain and fluent in how floating point works in detail.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `double` for more precision (or `BigDecimal` if you expect to work with very big numbers).

```
String aa = "1000009.00";
double bb = Double.parseDouble(aa);
bb=Math.round(bb*100);
System.out.printf("%.2f", bb); // it prints only two digits after the decimal point
```

**Output**

```
100000900.00
```

Comment: thx that works !

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`BigDecimal::multiply`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/math/BigDecimal.html#multiply(java.math.BigDecimal)) for example :

```
String aa = "1000009.00";
aa = aa.replaceAll(",", ".");
BigDecimal fullValue = new BigDecimal(aa);

System.out.println("full value  = " + fullValue.multiply(new BigDecimal(100)));
```

**Output**

```
full value  = 100000900.00
```

Comment: why this down-vote?

Comment: If you use `BigDecimal`, you should create it from `aa`, not `bb`, then use `movePointRight(2)` to get correct answer of `100000900`.

Comment: thank you @Andreas i don't read the question correctly check my answer now ?

Comment: Still not correct, since `1000009.00` multiplied by 100 should be `100000900`.

Comment: @Andreas what about now?